# jQuery .click() :active

Tags: jquery, css

Given the following code ([jFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qnt82os9/)):

```
<style>
div.bluebox {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}

div.greenbox {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}


div.greenbox:active{
  background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
<script>
$('.bluebox').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
    $('.greenbox').click();
});
</script>

<div class="bluebox">
</div>

<div class="greenbox">
</div>
```

If I click on the greenbox, then its background color changes to yellow. If I click on the bluebox, then the click event of the greenbox is triggered, but the background is still green. How can I tell jQuery to give greenbox the status active when click is executed indirectly?

Comment: You can't use triggered events to set styles via CSS pseudo selectors. You would have to add/remove a class on the `greenbox` element instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to set everything in your js.
like this:

```
$('.bluebox').mousedown(function(){
    $(".greenbox").css("backgroundColor", "yellow");
    }).mouseup(function(){
        $(".greenbox").css("backgroundColor", "green");
    });
$('.greenbox').mousedown(function(){
    $(".greenbox").css("backgroundColor", "yellow");
}).mouseup(function(){
    $(".greenbox").css("backgroundColor", "green");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1nxfy18v/

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

The code on `mousedown()` and `mouseup()` as we said in the comments :

```
$('.bluebox').mousedown(function(){
    $(".greenbox").toggleClass('active');
}).mouseup(function(){
  $(".greenbox").toggleClass('active');
});
```

[New fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1nxfy18v/4/)

---

You can't trigger `:active` CSS state with javascript. However, you can toggle a class instead to reproduce a similar behavior :

```
div.greenbox.active{
  background-color: yellow;
}

$('.bluebox').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
    $('.greenbox').toggleClass('active');
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/povqvfm1/2/)

Comment: Okay I see. But toggleClass would only change the background-color when I click, but I would like to change the background-color **during** the click. Is this also possible?

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan Thank you! But this doesnt work **during** the click. Here the color changes shortly after the click for a short moment.

Comment: Yes with setTimeout() as @RejithRKrishnan said, you can simulate this behavior

Comment: Thank you. I think its better to use mouseup/mousedown to simulate the click behavior (timeout doesnt work if you keep pressed with the mouse).

Comment: Yes, I think so too :)